# Retrofit + coroutines: Custom error handling with Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit v2.6.1 with `suspend` on the API calls.

```
interface Service {
    @POST("/login")
    suspend fun login(): User
}
```

My API sends custom Error responses that need to be parsed by Gson

```
{
    "message": "Credentials given does not identify a user or cannot be used to authenticate a user.",
    "error_code": "BAD_CREDENTIALS",
    "error_code_description": "Credentials given does not identify a user or cannot be used to authenticate a user.",
    "correlation_id": "api-fYXbwOaPzOjJ"
}
```

How do I customise the handling of these error responses working together with the coroutines?

Should I use Converters? TypeAdapters? Deserializers?

Comment: This json comes from server with code 200? Or some error code? Because if there is an error code in the response, you can use simple CallAdapterFactory like this https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/retrofit2/adapter/kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt with RetrofitException class (you can find it in goole). Then you can parse your error as you want, using generic converter Converter<ResponseBody, T>. Just try to google custom CallAdapterFactory + RetrofitException

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base Error class that all your models inherit from, like this

```
open class Error {
    val message: String? = null
    val error_code: String? = null
    val error_code_description: String? = null
    val correlation_id: String? = null
}

data class User(
        val name: String
) : Error()
```

You could also add methods to your base class to determine if it's an error,

```
open class Error {
    val message: String? = null
    val error_code: String? = null
    val error_code_description: String? = null
    val correlation_id: String? = null

    fun isErrorResponse() : Boolean = error_code != null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API returns always with the same template, you can create a serializable class and let GSON handle deserialization.

An example class for your case would be,

```
data class ErrorItem(
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("error_code")
    val message: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("error_code_description")
    val message: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("correlation_id")
    val message: String? = null,
)
```

Take a look at this for deserializer https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/retrofit-an-gson-deserialize-a-specific-object-type-based-on-the-value-of-a-field/10440/4

Comment: I already have an Error class, the problem is that the call expects one response (e.g. array) not an object

Comment: If it was java, I'd recommend using Generic types but my knowledge with Kotlin is limited. Maybe you can create a new ErrorArrayBase class ? That's all I can help.